# DMV CONNECTION_HOST_APPLICATION field is NULL

Tags: ssis, ssas, dmv

I am trying to monitor cubes and expressions of Analysis Services using DMV queries that are stored on Server's RAM.
I found many useful information about connections on connection's table of SSMS's DMVS rowser using the following mdx statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_CONNECTIONS
```

The problem is that the [CONNECTION_HOST_APPLICATION] field of connection's table is not recorded and contains null values for my client application.

> CONNECTION_HOST_APPLICATION specifies "The name of the machine that initiated the connection".

As a result i can not filter the rows that are generated from my client tool to analyse only them. So how can i modify my client tool in order to register this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of research, I, found the solution by adding the property of "application name" in connection string that connects to analysis services instance.

```
ApplicationName='testapp';
```

So now both SQL Server Profiler and DMVS are able to tracks application name.